# Using UWP TextBox.TextChanging to ignore wrong data

Tags: c#, events, textbox, uwp

I'm creating a UWP app which has different TextBoxes to enter numbers. To make sure only numbers can be entered I use the TextChanging event. Sadly I can't find any documentation on how to use TextChanging in detail to ignore wrong inputs.

A working solution for one TextBox is the following:

```
string oldText;
private void tbInput_TextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxTextChangingEventArgs args)
{
    double temp;
    if (double.TryParse(sender.Text, out temp) || sender.Text == "")
        oldText = sender.Text;
    else
    {
        int pos = sender.SelectionStart - 1;
        sender.Text = oldText;
        sender.SelectionStart = pos;
    }
}
```

Using this solution I would need a `string oldText` for each TextBox and either also a TextChanging function for each of it or a lot more code inside the function.

Is there a easy way to ignore "wrong" inputs in the TextBox.TextChanging event?

Comment: Are you aware of *InputScopes*? You may also take a look [at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21193669/2681948) - maybe will help.

Comment: I already set the _InputScope_ to `"Number"` but on the PC I can still enter letters... Your link looks good, I'll try this way.

Comment: There are probably couple of ways you can handle this task. Also you will probably have to handle the case when user copy-paste a text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the help of Romasz link in his first comment I came up with this solution:

```
private void tbInput_TextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxTextChangingEventArgs args)
{
    double dtemp;
    if (!double.TryParse(sender.Text, out dtemp) && sender.Text != "")
    {
        int pos = sender.SelectionStart - 1;
        sender.Text = sender.Text.Remove(pos, 1);
        sender.SelectionStart = pos;
    }
}
```

This works quite fine except when a part of the input value is selected and then a wrong character is entered.

Edit:
I improved the above version to use Regex. So now I'm able to check whatever content should be allowed to enter:

```
private void tbInput_TextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxTextChangingEventArgs args)
{
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(sender.Text, "^\\d*\\.?\\d*$") && sender.Text != "")
    {
        int pos = sender.SelectionStart - 1;
        sender.Text = sender.Text.Remove(pos, 1);
        sender.SelectionStart = pos;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I'm not having any problem "when a part of input is selected and then wrong char is entered"...it seems works fine. I will try improve its functionality with old code I got.

Answer (score 2):

Since the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (Build 16299) there is a textBox_BeforeTextChanging event. The TextBoxBeforeTextChangingEventArgs has a Cancel property to cancel the textchange. try this

```
    private void textBox_BeforeTextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxBeforeTextChangingEventArgs args)
    {
        bool result = int.TryParse(args.NewText, out int intResult);
        if (result == false || args.NewText.Contains(" "))
        {
            args.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

why ever he still accepts spaces, so i have to check them additionally.

Comment: Can you give an example of how using those events can help solve OP's problem, hopefully with a code sample?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [PreviewTextInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewtextinput(v=vs.110).aspx) event which passes the TextCompositionEventArgs that has a Handled property which can be used in the routing of the event to suspend the base control's implementation by setting Handled = true.

Comment: This sounds quite good, sadly the UWP TextBox doesn't have a PreviewTextInput event

Comment: That certainly is a disappointing turn, sorry I did not have my workstation with VS2015 available at the time I wrote it.

Comment: There are no PreviewEvents in UWP at all - not only in the TextBox.