# UWP: Binding + TextChanging = JIT win32 exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I am 100% sure I am doing this the wrong way and this problem is "by design".

I want to have a Slider and a TextBox that displays its value. The user can either use the Slider, or manually enter a number in the TextBox.

I also wanted to take advantage of the TextChanging event to ignore any non-numerical entries. TextChanged would only function after a user has entered something and it's not a preferable scenario, and KeyDown would not capture other methods of input like ink or speech.

So I have this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Slider x:Name="Size" Value="100" Maximum="100" Minimum="0" />
    <TextBox x:Name="SizeText" Text="{Binding ElementName=Size,Path=Value,Mode=TwoWay}" TextChanging="SizeText_TextChanging" />
</StackPanel>
```

Where "SizeText_TextChanging" is simply an empty block of code right now:

```
    private void SizeText_TextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxTextChangingEventArgs args)
    {
        // Nothing Here.
    }
```

This code builds, but at startup the app throws a JIT unhandled win32 exception and closes.

Changing TextChanging to TextChanged works fine, but again I prefer to get TextChanging to work (or something similar) to give a better user experience.

"Mode" also has no effect. I tried all three different Modes, all crash. By removing the binding altogether and giving the Text property any value works fine.

I also thought that maybe having the TextChanging event handler empty is the problem, so I borrowed the code below from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186357/using-uwp-textbox-textchanging-to-ignore-wrong-data) but the app still crashes:

```
private void SizeText_TextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxTextChangingEventArgs args)
{
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(sender.Text, "^\\d*\\.?\\d*$") && sender.Text != "")
    {
        int pos = sender.SelectionStart - 1;
        sender.Text = sender.Text.Remove(pos, 1);
        sender.SelectionStart = pos;
    }
}
```

Like I said, I am probably approaching this the wrong way. I am just starting to learn UWP and C# so I am a total noob. But I have read everything I could about TextChanging and it simply talks about rendering the value and the associated cautions of what not to write within the TextChanging event. So while it sounds like the app is being thrown into a loop trying to read the value of the slider and trying to see what the TextChanging event says, I don't see how to fix it. Please help!

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why this is happening, but a workaround is to register the `TextChanging` event handler only once `SizeText` (or the page) has loaded and using x:Bind instead of Binding:

**XAML**

```
<TextBox x:Name="SizeText" Text="{x:Bind Size.Value, Mode=TwoWay}" Loaded="SizeText_Loaded"/>
```

**CS**

```
private void SizeText_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SizeText.TextChanging += SizeText_TextChanging;
}

private void SizeText_TextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxTextChangingEventArgs args)
{
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. It gave me the same problem. Commenting out the event handler registration in SizeText_Loaded works so it seems like it is still relaying the problem.

Comment: Perfect! This worked with x:Bind. I am still confused why this behavior is happening (x:Bind and TextChanging also did not work but your suggestion of using the Loaded event first did). I know I have a lot to learn though. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem but this solution doesn't works for me.
As @Mushriq, I use **_TextChanging()** to ignore any non-numerical entries in a form.
But my form contains a lot of numeric fields and also a master-detail part, which contains 2 of these fields.
The problem is that I enter in the **_Loaded** the first time that I display a part, but not for the other parts. When I display existing parts there is no problem, but if I add a new part I get the exception.
Is there a way to adapt the solution to my case?